# When importing Custom ACE Editor Mode to Brace, requires calls does not find helper modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ace-editor, clickhouse

I have tried to implement a custom mode of [ACE Editor](https://ace.c9.io/) lib using [Brace](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace) (a browserify compatible version of the ace editor).

I have this ace modules that works fine on other project without Brace. When this code use the require function to import the modules/ext, inners requires got broken, even if I place the files on the correct folder.

Where does I have tried to place the files, then import

- Attempt 1: Node modules folder: `node_module/brace/mode/[files here]`
- Attempt 2: App folder: `src/ace/[files here]`

**Here is the error**:

```
mode-clickhouse.js?51d8:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClickhouseHighlightRules' of undefined
```

It seans that Require after import cant find import the module. The Ace mode is from the project [Tabix.io](https://github.com/tabixio/tabix), a GUI to ClickHouse

1. Path to Custom Mode ACE: [link](https://github.com/tabixio/tabix/blob/0e0b56dfa739c633a9a6fadaec506da600d92c0e/src/app/ace/mode-clickhouse.js)
2. Path to Custom Mode Submodules: [link](https://github.com/tabixio/tabix/tree/0e0b56dfa739c633a9a6fadaec506da600d92c0e/src/app/ace)

**Here is how I import this custom ACE Mode**. I am using Vue here, but I am sure that vue is not the issue generator.

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import * as brace from 'brace';
    // const ace = brace

    // OBS.: this one does not work
    // require('./ace/clickhouse_highlight_rule');
    // require('./ace/mode-clickhouse');

    // OBS.: this one does not work too
    import 'brace/mode/mode-clickhouse';

// ... more code
</script>
```

Here is the parte of code that get broken

```js
ace.define("ace/mode/clickhouse", ["require", "exports", "module", "ace/lib/oop", "ace/mode/text",
    "ace/token_iterator",
    "ace/mode/folding",
    "ace/mode/clickhouse_FoldMode",
    "ace/mode/clickhouse_highlight_rules"

], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";

    let oop = require("../lib/oop");
    let TextMode = require("./text").Mode;

// OBS.: ---> ERROR HERE
    let ClickhouseHighlightRules = require("./clickhouse_highlight_rules").ClickhouseHighlightRules;
    let ClickhouseFoldMode = require("./clickhouse_FoldMode").FoldMode;
    let MatchingBraceOutdent = require("./matching_brace_outdent").MatchingBraceOutdent;
    let CstyleBehaviour = require("./behaviour/cstyle").CstyleBehaviour;

    let Mode = function () {

        this.foldingRules = new ClickhouseFoldMode();
        this.$outdent = new MatchingBraceOutdent();
        this.$behaviour = new CstyleBehaviour();
        this.HighlightRules = ClickhouseHighlightRules;
    };

// more code here
```

Comment: Do you have any 404 in the browser?

Comment: @calebeaires Did you ever solve this?